# Can fscanf() read whitespace?

Tags: c, string, file-io

I've already got some code to read a text file using `fscanf()`, and now I need it modified so that fields that were previously whitespace-free need to allow whitespace.  The text file is basically in the form of:

> title: DATA 
>   title: DATA 
>   etc...

which is *basically* parsed using `fgets(inputLine, 512, inputFile); sscanf(inputLine, "%*s %s", &data);`, reading the DATA fields and ignoring the titles, but now some of the data fields need to allow spaces. I still need to ignore the title and the whitespace immediately after it, but then read in the rest of the line including the whitespace.

Is there anyway to do this with the `sscanf()` function?

If not, what is the smallest change I can make to the code to handle the whitespace properly?

UPDATE: I edited the question to replace fscanf() with fgets() + sscanf(), which is what my code is actually using. I didn't really think it was relevant when I first wrote the question which is why I simplified it to fscanf().

Comment: If you used to parse it using `scanf`, then you could also previously parse something like `title: DATA title: DATA` (i.e. all on one line). If you want to allow whitespace in values, then what will be the terminator? If newline, then it seems that your original code was a bit too lax...

Comment: Also, how do you decide on the size of `str` buffer, and how do you ensure that it does not overflow?

Comment: yes, when the DATA can have whitespace the newline will be used as the terminator

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you cannot use `fgets()` use the `%[` conversion specifier (with the "exclude option"):

```
char buf[100];
fscanf(stdin, "%*s %99[^\n]", buf);
printf("value read: [%s]\n", buf);
```

**But `fgets()` is way better.**

---

*Edit: version with `fgets()` + `sscanf()`*

```
char buf[100], title[100];
fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin); /* expect string like "title: TITLE WITH SPACES" */
sscanf(buf, "%*s %99[^\n]", title);
```

Comment: For this particular case, how is `fgets` "way better"?

Comment: Well ... the requirements keep changing (first there was no space in the string). It isn't better for this particular case, but it is better to use `fgets()` now, in antecipation for the next change of requirements :)

Comment: I updated the question to show that I actually do use fgets() to read the line, then sscanf() to parse it, but is there a better way to parse the line after fgets()?

Comment: `fgets()` + `sscanf()` is a good way to parse (simple) strings.

Comment: If it gets more complicated, you can try regex. If it gets even more complicated, you'll need to write a proper parser (though something like flex/bison, or many other parser generators, would help with that).

Comment: Is this %[ thing standard C89? I never saw it before.

Comment: @Calmarius: yes, it's Standard C89. I don't have a reference for C89, but you can read about it in [7.19.6.2 in Standard C99](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.19.6.2).

Comment: Wait ... here's the [link to 4.9.6.2 in C89 Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#4.9.6.2)

Answer (score 3):

I highly suggest you stop using `fscanf()` and start using `fgets()` (which reads a whole line) and then parse the line that has been read.

This will allow you considerably more freedom in regards to parsing non-exactly-formatted input.

Comment: I updated the question to show that I actually do use fgets(), but I don't understand what exactly it will help. I still have to parse the line once I read it in.

Comment: Once you've got the entire string, walk it yourself rather than using sscanf.

Comment: Yes, do it with pointers, or even better use regular expressions. If you used C++ I would have suggested boost; I don't know of any good C libraries but there must be some. I heard POSIX supports them.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest thing would be to issue a

```
fscanf("%*s");
```

to discard the first part and then just call the fgets:

```
fgets(str, stringSize, filePtr);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you insist on using `scanf`, and assuming that you want newline as a terminator, you can do this:

```
scanf("%*s %[^\n]", str);
```

Note, however, that the above, used exactly as written, is a bad idea because there's nothing to guard against `str` being overflown (as `scanf` doesn't know its size). You can, of course, set a predefined maximum size, and specify that, but then your program may not work correctly on some valid input.

If the size of the line, as defined by input format, isn't limited, then your only practical option is to use `fgetc` to read data char by char, periodically reallocating the buffer as you go. If you do that, then modifying it to drop all read chars until the first whitespace is fairly trivial.

Answer (score 3):

A `%s` specifier in fscanf skips any whitespace on the input, then reads a string of non-whitespace characters up to and not including the next whitespace character.

If you want to read up to a newline, you can use `%[^\n]` as a specifier.  In addition, a ' ' in the format string will skip whitespace on the input.  So if you use

```
fscanf("%*s %[^\n]", &str);
```

it will read the first thing on the line up to the first whitespace ("title:" in your case), and throw it away, then will read whitespace chars and throw them away, then will read all chars up to a newline into str, which sounds like what you want.

Be careful that str doesn't overflow -- you might want to use

```
fscanf("%*s %100[^\n]", &str)
```

to limit the maximum string length you'll read (100 characters, not counting a terminating NUL here).

Comment: I know this is a short example but do you have to use the address of str? I would think this would also work. `fscanf("%*s %[^\n]", str);`

Answer (score 1):

You're running up against the limits of what the `*scanf` family is good for.  With fairly minimal changes you could try using the string-scanning modules from Dave Hanson's [C Interfaces and Implementations](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/software/cii/).  This stuff is a retrofit from the programming language [Icon](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/icon/), an extremely simple and powerful string-processing language which Hanson and others worked on at Arizona.  The departure from `sscanf` won't be too severe, and it is simpler, easier to work with, and more powerful than regular expressions.  The only down side is that the code is a little hard to follow without the book—but if you do much C programming, the book is well worth having.