# Read whitespaces with fscanf

Tags: c, file, scanf

I want to read from a file which stores data like this:

```
Max Mustermann 12345
```

Now I want to read the data with this code:

```
FILE *datei;
char text[100];
int il;

datei = fopen ("datei.txt", "r");

if (datei != NULL)
{
    fscanf(datei, ": %s %d", text, &il);

    printf("%s %d", text, il);
    fclose(datei);
}
```

But this code scans only 'Max' (because there is a whitespace) and then the next 'Mustermann' as int. I want to sotre 'Max Mustermann' is the char array and '12345' in the int varaible. What can I do to read whitespaces with fscanf? Or is there an other way to get values in different varaibles from the file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can fscanf() read whitespace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950057/can-fscanf-read-whitespace)

Comment: The colon in the format string requires a colon in the data — and there isn't a colon in your sample data.  Also, you ***must*** check the return value from `fscanf()` and friends to ensure you got the data you expected.  With those preliminaries said, I'm not sure this is a good fit for `fscanf()`; there isn't an easy way to tell it when to stop scanning the name and start scanning the number.

Comment: @WhozCraig: the question you link to recommends `%34[^\n]` (a scan set; exact format to be determined).  The only way to apply that here is probably `%99[^0-9]` or thereabouts.

Comment: Given the confines of the intended outcome then, I would likely not use fscanf at all, rather just to `fgets()`, put a pointer at the last char, and walk backward until BOS or it is no longer a digit-char. I like BLUE's part1-answer below, but it relies on the whitespace separator to actually be a *space*; a tab (or worse, no separator at all) hoses the algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *datei;
    char text[100];
    char line[128], *p;
    int il;

    datei = fopen ("data.txt", "r");

    if (datei != NULL){
        if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), datei) != 0){ //read one line
            p=strrchr(line, ' ');//search last space
            *p = '\0';//split at last space
            strcpy(text, line);
            il = atoi(p+1);//or sscanf(p+1, "%d", &il);
            printf("%s, %d", text, il);
        }
        fclose(datei);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

also use fscanf.

```
char *p;
//"%[^0123456789] is reading other digit character
fscanf(datei, "%[^0123456789]%d", text, &il);
p=strrchr(text, ' ');//search last space
*p = '\0';//replace last space (meant drop)
printf("%s, %d", text, il);
```

hand made?

```
#include <ctype.h>
    if (datei != NULL){
        int ch, i=0;
        while(EOF!=(ch=fgetc(datei)) && i<100-1){
            if(isdigit(ch)){
                ungetc(ch, datei);
                text[--i] = '\0';
                break;
            }
            text[i++] = ch;
        }
        if(i >= 99){
            fprintf(stderr, "It does not conform to the format\n");//maybe no
            fclose(datei);
            return -1;
        }
        fscanf(datei, "%d", &il);
        printf("%s, %d\n", text, il);
        fclose(datei);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks to Jonathan Leffler.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the format of the file. If it is always `first-name space last-name space number` then you can use two %s to get first and last name.

```
if (fscanf(datei, "%s %s %d", text1, text2, &il) == 3)
    ...then OK...
else
    ...failed...
```

If for example, the number is preceded by a special/unique character (let's say a "!") then you can use a scanf format like this ?

```
if (fscanf(datei, "%[^!]!%d", text, &il) != 2)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can guarantee there are always two names before the number, or the file can be delimeted (maybe a comma between name and number), then there isn't really any way to do what you want, automatically.

What if the name was: Max Mustermann 3rd

I think the data input file needs 'cleaning' before you can process it.

Comment: Of course it can be done.  You just parse it from the end of the line as BLUEPIXY did in his/her answer.