# I want to make fscanf keep scanning even with spaces in the input

Tags: c, scanf

I got this line:

```
fscanf(file, "%s %[^\t\n]", message);
```

Now when it scans I get all the chars until the space, but I want it to read until the end of the line instead of only up to a space.

Comment: You may also want to have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950057/can-fscanf-read-whitespace

Comment: I'm surprised that you don't get a crash since there's nowhere for that `fscanf()` call to put the data it reads in for the `%[` conversion spec.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't entirely clear what you are after.  If you want all the data on the line up to the newline (and you want the newline read), then it is simplest to use `fgets()`:

```
if (fgets(message, sizeof(message), file) != 0)
{
    size_t len = strlen(message);
    if (message[len-1] == '\n')
        message[len-1] = '\0';
    else
        ...line was too long to fit in message...
    ...use message...
}
```

If you must use `fscanf()`, then you might use:

```
char message[256];

if (fscanf(file, "%255[^\n]", message) == 1)
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF && c != '\n')
        ;    // Ignore characters to newline
    ...use message...
}
```

In your version, you have (at least) three problems:

```
fscanf(file, "%s %[^\t\n]", message);
```

1. You have to conversion specifications which assign, but you only provide one variable.
2. You do not check the return value from `fscanf()`, so you don't know whether it worked or not.
3. Your format string does not do what you think it does.

The first two issues are fairly straight-forward.  The last is not.  Spaces in `scanf()`-family format strings represent arbitrary sequences of white space (except inside a scan set).  So, the blank in the format string will read the white space (blanks, tabs, newlines, etc) up until there's something in the input that doesn't match white space.  That means a letter, digit or punctuation character for many purposes.  Then a sequence of such characters will be read into the variable that you provided when fixing problem 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char msg1[256];
  char msg2[256];
  int  n;

  if ((n = scanf("%s %[^\t\n]", msg1, msg2)) == 2)
    printf("1: <<%s>>\n2: <<%s>>\n", msg1, msg2);
  else
    printf("Oops: %d\n", n);
  return 0;
}
```

Sample run:

```
$ ./scan
abracadabra


          widgets
1: <<abracadabra>>
2: <<sigets>>
$
```

If you want to read up to a newline (or tab) in `message`, then you need:

```
if (fscanf(file, "%[^\t\n]", message) != 1)
    ...oops...
else
    ...use message...
```

Answer (score -1):

In C when reading C String you should use the gets family instead of scanf familly

```
char * gets ( char * str );
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/?kw=gets

```
char * fgets ( char * str, int num, FILE * stream );
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/

These read until EOL char is found or a certain limit of chars is reached (in order to not get a buffer overflow)

**Edit**

Here's how to read a whole file line by line

```
while ( fgets ( line, size_of_buffer , file ) != NULL ){ /* read a line */
     fputs ( line, stdout ); /* write the line */
}
```

The condition in the while loop makes sure that the file did not end.

As said in the comment gets is a very dangerous function and should not be used.

Comment: But if I want it to read until the end of the line(there is more information in the next line)?

Comment: EOL = end of line. These functions read until the end of the line. You can read line by line using this in a while loop and verify if the returned value is not null ( which usually happens when the end of file is reached ).
If you want to read a whole file in a single string that implies first finding out the size of the file, allocating a string big enough for the whole file and than reading the file in binary mode. But this method is not recommended.

Comment: I'd avoid suggesting `gets()` since there's no way it can be used safely with arbitrary input.

Comment: Time for my favourite man page quote: "Never use `gets()`.  Because it is impossible to tell without knowing the data in advance how many  characters  `gets()`  will  read,  and  because `gets()` will continue to store characters past the end of the buffer, it is extremely dangerous to use.  It has  been  used  to  break  computer
security.  Use `fgets()` instead." Also, `gets` has been removed from the language in the 2011 standard (yay!).

Comment: I was just telling him about them mate. I know gets shouldn't be used , and that's what also says at the cplusplus link if u check.
The most recent revision of the C standard (2011) has definitively removed this function from its specification.
"The function is deprecated in C++ (as of 2011 standard, which follows C99+TC3)."

Comment: Note that `gets()` was one of the attack vectors for the first Internet Worm (the Morris Worm) way back in 1988.