# Read characters with space characters from text file in C

Tags: c

I try to read text file looks like

[mytextfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pwlI.png)

```
int main() 
{
FILE *file;

char k[200][2];
int i=0;

if((file=fopen("blobs1.txt","r"))!=NULL);
{
        
    while(!feof(file))
    {
     fscanf(file,"%s",&k[i]);
     printf("%s",k[i]);
         
    
}
    
}
```

and result is:1020xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

but I want it to be like the picture.Where am I doing wrong ? Thank you.

Comment: Your `fscanf(...,"%s",...);` reads everything except for spaces

Comment: You are using `feof` incorrectly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950057/can-fscanf-read-whitespace

Comment: Your code does not appear to care about newlines at all.  It seems that you are just trying to implement a standard `while( (c = fgetc(f)) != EOF ) putchar(c);`

Comment: General rule: if you are a beginner (or intermediate, whatever that means) with C, do *not* use scanf.  At all.  Avoid it until you have (literally) 15 years of experience with the language.

Answer (score 0):

`fscanf()` with `%s` will skip whitespace character. You should use `fgets()` to read whole lines.

Also your usage of `while(!feof(file))` is [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) and you should check if readings are successful before using what are "read".

Another note is that having semicolon in the `if` line is bad because it will disable the `NULL` check and have it try to read things from `NULL` when the `fopen` fails.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *file;

    char k[200][2];
    int i=0;

    if((file=fopen("blobs1.txt","r"))!=NULL)
    {
        
        while(fgets(k[i], sizeof(k[i]), file) != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s",k[i]);
            
        
        }
        
        fclose(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank's a lot,I appreciate that

Answer (score 0):

If you really want scanf/fscanf, try `"[^\n]"` instead of `"%s"`. It will read until the line terminator '\n' or end the of the file.